# Pandas not matching zero or more digits/characters when extracting a string from a dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, extract

I'm using Anaconda 4.4.0. I'm getting unexpected matching behavior when trying to match using 0 or more characters. My pattern seems to only work at the beginning of the string value, rather than matching anywhere.

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(['#aaaaab_1', 'xxaab_3', 'aaab_5', 'xab_8','ab_13','b_21', '666xyz'] )
temp[0].str.extract('([a-z]*)', expand=True)

       0
0            <--missing value
1  xxaab
2   aaab
3    xab
4     ab
5      b
6            <--missing value

temp[0].str.extract('([0-9]*)', expand=True)

     0
0           <--missing value    
1           <--missing value    
2           <--missing value         
3           <--missing value         
4           <--missing value         
5           <--missing value         
6  666
```

The matching behavior seems to go back to what I expect when extracting one or more characters/digits.

```
temp[0].str.extract('([0-9]+)', expand=True)

     0
0    1
1    3
2    5
3    8
4   13
5   21
6  666

 temp[0].str.extract('([a-z]+)', expand=True)

        0
0  aaaaab
1   xxaab
2    aaab
3     xab
4      ab
5       b
6     xyz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that `str.extract` finds the first search (which is also satisfied by the null string, which is the reason for your output) and then returns that match without looking any further. It just so happened that the 2<sup>nd</sup> through 6<sup>th</sup> rows returned more than a null string, because the null string was followed by more matching characters.

The solution, as you've already discerned, is to modify your regex in such a way that null strings can never match (i.e, avoiding the use of `*`).

Answer (score 1):

You do not get any missing values, you get empty strings. (They are not the same.) `'([0-9]*)'` matches any empty string of digits, and the first six rows of your dataframe surely begin with an empty string of digits. You should either demand a string of at least one digit `'([0-9]+)'` or "cheat" the regex by first asking for any string of non-digits, followed by any string of digits:

```
temp[0].str.extract('[^0-9]*([0-9]*)', expand=True)
#     0
#0    1
#1    3
#2    5
#3    8
#4   13
#5   21
#6  666
```